# Pytest ignores all options to make it less verbose

Tags: python, pytest, python-poetry

I am using pytest (inside a poetry enviroment) and no matter which option I find online, I can not get pytest to get less verbose. It always does the same.

```
poetry run python -m pytest ./my_tests
```

I tried `-q` `--quiet` `--show-capture=no` `--log-cli-level=warning` as options, but it changes nothing. It still shows me all passed, skipped and failed tests in same detail.

Is this a bug with using poetry and pytest or am I missing something?

I am using
Poetry 1.4.2
Python 3.10.6
Pytest 7.2.2

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Do you have any default settings in either `pyproject.toml` or `pytest.ini`? Try running `pytest -h` to see the defaults without any command line switches. Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/customize.html

Comment: By "quiet" what are you hoping for? You can always run `pytest > /dev/null | echo Test Failed` in a shell command.